# I can't find proper regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following file(like this scheme, but much longer):

```
LSE           ZTX                       
    SWX         ZURN                    
LSE           ZYT
NYSE                            CGI
```

There are 2 words (like i.e. `LSE ZTX`) in every line with optional spaces and/or  tabs at the beginning, at the end and always in between.
Could someone help me to match these 2 words with regexp? Following the example I wish to have LSE in $1 and ZTX in $2 for the first line, SWX in $1 and  ZURN in $2 for the second etc. 
I have tried something like:

```
$line =~ /(\t|\s)*?(.*?)(\t|\s)*?(.*?)/msgi;
$line =~ /[\t*\s*]?(.*?)[\t*\s*]?(.*?)/msgi;
```

I don't know how can I say, that there could be either spaces or tabs (or both of them mixed, so for ex. \t\s\t)

Comment: It sounds like all you need is `split ' ',  $line`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just match the two first words, the most basic thing is to just match any sequence of characters that are not whitespace:

```
my ($word1, $word2) = $line =~ /\S+/g;
```

This will capture the first two words in `$line` into the variables, if they exist. Note that parentheses are not required when using the `/g` modifier. Use an array instead if you want to capture *all* existing matches.

Answer (score 3):

Always two words, you don't need to match the entire line, so your most simple regex would be:

```
/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

`\s` includes also tabulation so your regex looks like:

```
$line =~ /^\s*([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)/;
```

the first word is in the first group ($1) and the second in $2.

You can change `[A-Z]` to whatever's more convenient with your needs.

Here is the explanation from [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm)

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\s*([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
^\s*([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33bfm), you find the first code of a row in group 1 and the second in group 2. `\s` is a whitespace character, it includes e.g. spaces, tabs and newline characters.

In Perl it is something like this:

```
($code1, $code2) = $line =~ /^\s*([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)/i;
```

I think you are reading the text file row by row, so you don't need the modifiers `s` and `m`, and `g` is also not needed.

In case the codes are not only ASCII letters, then replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{L}`. `\p{L}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that will match every letter in every language.

Answer (score 1):

With option "Multiline" this Regex:

```
^\s*(?<word1>\S+)\s+(?<word2>\S+)\s*$
```

Will give you N matches each containing 2 groups named:
- word1 
- word2

Answer (score 1):

`^\s*([A-Z]{3,4})\s+([A-Z]{3,4})$`

What this does

```
^             // Matches the beginning of a string
\s*           // Matches a space/tab character zero or more times
([A-Z]{3,4})  // Matches any letter A-Z either 3 or 4 times and captures to $1
\s+           // Then matches at least one tab or space
([A-Z]{3,4})  // Matches any letter A-Z either 3 or 4 times and captures to $2
$             // Matches the end of a string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $word1, $word2 ) = split;
    print "($word1, $word2)\n";
}

__DATA__
LSE         ZTX                       
    SWX         ZURN                    
LSE         ZYT
NYSE                            CGI
```

Output:

```
(LSE, ZTX)
(SWX, ZURN)
(LSE, ZYT)
(NYSE, CGI)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the spaces at the start of the line are what you use to identify your codes you want, try this:

Split your string up at newlines, then try this regex:

```
^\s+(\w+\s+){2}$
```

This will only match lines that start with some space, followed by a (word - some space - word), then end with some space.

```
# ^           --> String start
# \s+         --> Any number of spaces
# (\w+\s+){2} --> A (word followed by some space)x2
# $           --> String end.
```

**However**, if you want to capture the codes alone, [try this](http://regexr.com?33bfj):

```
$line =~ /^\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;

# \s*   --> Zero or more whitespace,
# (\w+) --> Followed by a word (group #1),
# \s+   --> Followed by some whitespace,
# (\w+) --> Followed by a word (group #2),
```

Comment: This will not match lines that do not have a space. The spaces were explained to be optional at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @ZackT.: I was assuming the spaces at the start of the line is what the user identifies the strings with, that he wants to obtain. That is the only way these could possibly be identified, and it seems like the user wants to find codes that could have those spaces.
Unless the question is clarified, this actually answers the question. No reason to downvote.

Comment: I don't think he wants to capture ONLY the codes with spaces, I think he's saying that any line could have some spaces or tabs before the actual code, then some more spaces or tabs, and then another code, and he wants to get all of the codes.

Comment: @ZackT.: `There are 2 codes with optional spaces and/or tabs <...> Could someone help me to math these 2 codes with regexp?` Read the darn question.

Comment: What the hell is "math these 2 codes" supposed to mean anyway? The question is not very well formed.

Comment: @ZackT.: The question might be a little unclear, but as it is right now, this does answer the question. Especially since the OP is searching for spaces in his regex, at the start of the line.

Comment: Sorry! It was a typo. I mean "match" and not math.

Answer (score -2):

This will match all your codes

```
/[A-Z]+/
```